# Help needed for writing an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, random

Here is the description of the the problem

Given an integer N, write a function which returns an integer array of size N, containing the numbers from 1 to N in a random order. Each number from 1 to N must appear once and must not repeat.

- What is the running time of your algorithm?
- Can your algorithm be improved?

For example: if you are given the number 4, your output must generate something like 4213, 2413, 3124, etc.

Invalid outputs would be 1123, 4444, 244.

Any ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: If this is a homework, tag it as such please.

Comment: What language is to be used? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Would 1234 count as a random order too? It is the easiest to generate. If not, please define 'random'.

Comment: yup! sounds like homework! I agree with Henk: what do you exactly mean by random?

Comment: Isn't that a simple shuffle of the numbers 1 through N? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: It certainly is a homework, so I am re-tagging it..... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hint:  look up what a Fisher-Yates shuffle is.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's home work. I just finished writing the algorithm in java, but using Fisher-Yates shuffle seems to be much more efficient. Thank you people. Below is my version of the algorithm.

```
Collection<Integer> generateNumbers(int n) {
    Collection<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int max = 0;        
    int min = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        max=(max*10)+n;
        min=(min*10)+1;
    }
    while(numbers.size()<n){
        int random = rand.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
        int temp = random;
        boolean good = true;
        Set<Integer> digits = new HashSet<Integer>();
        while(temp>0 && good){
            int reminder = temp%10;
            if(reminder > 0 && reminder <= n ){ 
                digits.add(reminder);
            }else
                good = false;
            temp/=10;
        }       
        if(good && digits.size() == n)
        numbers.add(random);
    }       
    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: that thing you're doing with min and max seems unnecessary

Comment: Isn't a `HashSet` unordered?  Doesn't this defeat the purpose?

Comment: @Ben: You are right, I missed a minor part of the actual question. Thanks.

Comment: @Svante: I don't care what the order is, I need to make sure there is no duplicates. What do you think is a better option?

Comment: The problem description says "random order".  The "order" of things in a HashSet is not random, but predetermined by the hash implementation; you should treat this order as nonexistent, which is not the same as "random" at all.  You should use a collection with a defined order, e.g. ArraySet.  Actually, you should just use an array, put the numbers in in order, and finally do an unbiased shuffle.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is shuffling an integer array.

Here's an explanation of the **[Knuth shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)**.